# How to delete a file stored in my device using OnItemLongClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which display all the files inside a folder.
What is the method to delete a file using OnItemLongClickListener?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know what you want.Just remove the file in your listener .   File file = new File(fileName); file.delete();  the fileName can be got from your listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `OnItemLongClickListener()` method call this method. Here path.get(position) is a ArrayList that I used. You should change it by giving your file location according to your requirement.

```
 public void doDeleteFile(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        File fileToDelete = new File(path.get(position));

        if(!fileToDelete.isDirectory()){

            try{
                if(fileToDelete.delete()){
                    System.out.println("File deleted successfull !");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("File delete operation failed");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Exception :"+ex.getMessage());
            }

        }else{

            System.out.println("It is  not a file");

        }
```